# auth middleware changes request type from POST to GET

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.3

I have a simple comment form on every page with a model.The form is visible for non-logged users.

When a non-logged user submits the comment, the request is caught by `auth` middleware.

The form action is `comments`.

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'comments', 'method' =>'post', 'role'=>'form', 'class'=>'')) !!}
```

I have a resource route defined in my routes file:
`Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');`

After logging successfully, the user is redirected to `comments`, but here is the problem:

### problem

The user is redirected to `index` method of the controller.
It seems that the middleware resets the request type from `POST` to `GET`.

The problem is present in all past and the most recent Laravel 5.3.

Relevant Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

### My question

Is this behavior "a feature", or should I report a bug in Laravel?

### my hotfix

I changed the url definition in form header to `comments/create` and added a new route above the `resource`. But it doesn't look like a elegant resolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just have the users log in before they can place a comment? Perhaps disable the comment text box/area and then have a "login to comment" button. By having them log in before being able to actually write a comment you'll save yourself such a headache

Comment: You can always work some magic with ajax and popup a bootstrap modal (assuming you are using bootstrap) asking the user to login or comment and once ajax logs the user in, submit the form without losing any of the data the user put in.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bug,
After user logged in successfully, user will be redirected back to "comments".
Redirection is really a GET method, you cant redirect using POST method.

This link will support that you cant use POST in redirect,
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-do-redirect-in-php-with-post-and-not-get/4968/7

you can either use session to store the previous POST values and save it after

Comment: `"you cant redirect using POST method"`
So it is not a Laravel-related `feature`, but simply how PHP works?

It seems that the only solution is to make an extra route to handle requests for comment submission

Comment: yup, thats how redirect works (only GET)
you could either make an extra route for the redirection,
or write extra code in you login controller to save the comments

Comment: If you really want to have this seamless post, you can, however, intercept and capture the post content, and redirect them to login, redirect back to comments, and continue the submission using the caught post data. It's messy, but it should work.